# how to get flutter future.wait response?

Tags: flutter, dart

how to get flutter future.wait response??? i have done a casting but it still doesn't work.

error:

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: type 'Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Map<String, dynamic>>' in type cast
```

code:

```
Future<void> addNewTask(User data, [BuildContext context]) async {

    Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> responses = Future.wait([
      Database.addUser(uid, data.toMap()),
      Database.addSetting(uid, data.toMap())
    ]);

     List<Map<String, dynamic>> firstResponse = responses as List<Map<String, dynamic>>;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `await` just before `Future.wait([...`? Looking at https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Future/wait.html, `Future.wait` still returns a future thats to be completed once the futures specified complete themselves.

Comment: try this List<Map<String, dynamic>> responses= Future.wait([ ...

Comment: @GilesCorreiaMorton yes you are right!

Answer (score 1):

here is the correct answer. added an await in front of `future.await` and remove the future from `List<Map<String, dynamic>>`

```
Future<void> addNewTask(User data, [BuildContext context]) async {

    List<Map<String, dynamic>> responses = await Future.wait([
      Database.addUser(uid, data.toMap()),
      Database.addSetting(uid, data.toMap())
    ]);
}
```